# Let 3k users flag posts for closure after using all their close votes

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close

Today, I burned through all my close votes (turns out 50 < 53k!).

I saw a question which should be NARQ, and went to close it as such. Hit the close button and...

[image: no close votes]

No close votes remaining. Great! The system works.

So, I thought, I shall flag this and make it show up in the close votes queue:

[image: no flags?]

Huh. The vote-to-close button is available! Maybe it will send it to the close votes queue without giving me any trouble.

[image: nope]

Nope.

If I'm trusted to *make* the decision about whether something should be closed, why can't I notify *others* to make this decision? Am I trusted to take action, but not to flag? Do I really *lose* the flagging privilege when I hit 3k?

So, I propose we change the above screen to this when I have used all my close votes:

[image]

And a flag from a 3k user would, just like a flag from a <3k user, send it to the close votes queue and decrement my flag count for the day. Unlike a 3k user, the flags shouldn't get marked as anything - it should be marked as `none`, so I don't get credit for it.

Comment: So after you reduce the close queue by 50, you want to increase it back up?

Comment: You can still use a custom flag you know.

Comment: @djechlin Instead of decreasing the amount of time a bad question is here, you want to *increase* it?

Comment: @djechlin As long as it's not the same 50 questions, I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: @Asad Yes, I could, but *mods* have to look at Custom flags. I just want it to go into the general, 3k-accessible queue. Where it's less likely to get rejected as *don't flag stuff you can fix on your own!*

Comment: If this *were* implemented, the flags shouldn't get marked as helpful or declined. It should *only* be a way of making it pop into the review queue.

Comment: Something needs to be done about the close queue, as I've been complaining about for some while now.  But insofar as these limits exist for a reason, converting your close-energy into work for the mods is not a good improvement on status quo.  You've expressed your opinion 50 times in a given day and got throttled.  Just don't burn all 50 votes, keep 10 back for sporadic or more serious problems you see.

Comment: @djechlin And if I see 10 serious problems?

Comment: @animuson Yes, I was thinking the same. Just a 'hey, this is here' type of thing.

Comment: @Undo Well, then everything worked out OK, didn't it. Did you mean "more than 10"?

Comment: @Asad Woops. 11 problems.

Comment: This is a dupe. I know because I asked this very question a few years ago. Let me see if I can scare up a link.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Really? I tried to find something - close it!

Comment: Duplicate because the answer is the same, and in the comments, it's noted that this is the behavior for all close votes, not just duplicates.